# Read Video path using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How to read video path using javascript and pass it to html source value. Currently I am using hard coded from my html to read video and I want it to be dynamic to javascript. Here is my Temporary loading from content folder in my project:

```
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata" style="width:100%; height:100%">
      <source src="~/Content/Videos/Sample_Vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">                                     
</video>
```

Comment: Read video path from where? Query parameters?

Comment: nope just folder path from my project(local) so that if I am going to publish it will just read the same path.

Comment: Do you mean you want to dynamically add the video element to your page using javascript? ie, you know the path of your video in javascript, and you want to add the video to the page on the client?

Comment: You can use relative path in the src attribute. (ie. put the video file at the same location of your html file then change `src` to`"Sample_Vid.mp4"`)

Comment: @DacreDenny yup that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you could:

1. implement a function like `setVideoSource()` as shown below, which would allow you to set/change the source of a video element that already exists in your page or,
2. implement a function like `addVideo()` as shown below, which would allow you to dynamically create/add a new video element to your page with a source of your choosing

Please see the documentation below for detail on how both functions work:

```js
/*
Updates the source of first video in the document matching the selector
*/
function setVideoSource(selector, src) {
  
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  
  /* 
  Check that element is video before proceeding 
  */
  if(element.nodeName === 'VIDEO') {
    
    /* 
    If element is a video, remove any source children if present
    */
    for(const source of element.querySelectorAll('source')) {
      element.removeChild(source);
    }
    
    /* 
    Create a new source element and populate it with the src
    attribute 
    */
    const source = document.createElement('source');    
    source.setAttribute('src', src);    
    
    /*
    Add source element to the video we're updating
    */
    element.appendChild(source);    
  }
}

/*
Adds a new video to the document under the first element matching the parentSelector
*/
function addVideo(parentSelector, src, width, height) {
  
  const parent = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
  
  /* 
  Check that parent exists before proceeding
  */
  if(parent) {
    
    /* 
    Create new video element
    */
    const video = document.createElement('video');      
    video.setAttribute('controls', true);      
    
    if(width) {
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
    }
    
    if(height) {
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
    }
    
    /* 
    Create a new source element and populate it with the src
    attribute 
    */
    const source = document.createElement('source');    
    source.setAttribute('src', src);    
    
    /*
    Add source element to the video we're inserting and add
    the video element to the document element
    */
    video.appendChild(source);    
    parent.appendChild(video);    
  }
}

// Update source of existing video
setVideoSource('#video', 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4')

// Add a new video to the page
addVideo('#parent', 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4', '100%', '150px')
```

```html
<h3>Existing video dynamically updated with JavaScript</h3>
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <source src="~/Content/Videos/Sample_Vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
</video>

<h3>New video dynamically added to page with JavaScript</h3>
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried it to my page it actually works, but my problem is how can I change the size same from the first video or based from my video.

Comment: Nice - so just to clarify, if you're adding a video using the script above, then you also want to be able to supply the dimensions as well?

Comment: yep! just want to simply resize it

Comment: and also just want to know because my target is from local path in drive c but it seems like not taking it

Comment: addVideo('#parent', 'C:/www/mySite.com/Content/Videos/main.mp4')

Comment: @Rockn'Roll no problems - I've just updated the `addVideo()` function in the snippet above which lets you provide an optional `width` and `height` for the video being added (see end of snippet for usage example).

Comment: Also, you typically can't access content like video media directly off the harddrive (ie from C:/) as you require (browsers usually prevent this for security reasons). You will want to host such media via a local server. If you're familiar with node/npm, then you can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server to start a local server by simply entering 'http-server' in the command terminal from the folder that your video is in. Hope that helps

Comment: Do note that a "local path" means "local to the browser": someone else visiting this site will probably not see it

Comment: im not familiar yet on it, is there other way to loads it locally through javascript? or c# code?

Comment: There are two things here: first, you need to serve the video (via http-server as mentioned above, or via say IIS/C#). Second, you need to fetch the video - this is done via HTML or JavaScript (as shown above). The fetching part is described in my answer above and assumes you have a server set up to actually serve the video being fetched

Comment: ok thanks for the info got your point now. seems like I really need to do it from my back end c# to fetch the video then load it via ajax and display it to my html.